# T-SQL Do not ignore NULL values in SUM

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, cumulative-sum

I am trying to add running totals to a table, on a NULL value the running total should be NULL. However SUM ignores NULL values.

Is there a way to not ignore NULL in SUM?

```
SELECT
    run_key,
    time_empty,
    SUM(time_empty) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2 ORDER BY run_key ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW) as time_empty_rt
FROM 
    tblmytable
ORDER BY 
    run_key
```

[image]

Comment: Provide sample data what you selecting and check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a partition for each group that has the same number of preceding `null` columns.

```
select  run_key
,       time_empty
,       sum(time_empty) over (
            partition by preceding_nulls
            order by run_key 
            rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as time_emtpy_rt
from    (
        select  sum(case when time_empty is null then 1 else 0 end) over (
                    order by run_key 
                    rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as preceding_nulls
        ,       *
        from    YourTable yt
        ) sub
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/47969/4/0)

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anyway to approach this other than in two steps, first as a [gaps and islands problem](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf) to identify your islands to sum up, then to do the sum. So first the islands:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (run_key INT, time_empty INT, Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
INSERT @T (run_key, time_empty) 
VALUES
    (1, 637), (2, NULL), (3, NULL), (4, NULL), 
    (5, 2967), (6, 1000), (7, NULL), (8, NULL);

SELECT  run_key,
        time_empty, 
        IslandID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Run_key) - 
                    ROW_NUMBER() 
                                OVER(PARTITION BY 
                                        Col1, 
                                        Col2, 
                                        CASE WHEN time_empty IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                                    ORDER BY Run_key)
FROM    @T
ORDER BY run_key;
```

Which gives:

```
run_key time_empty  IslandID
------------------------------
1       637         0
2       NULL        1
3       NULL        1
4       NULL        1
5       2967        3
6       1000        3
7       NULL        3
8       NULL        3
```

This now gives you a column (`IslandID`) to partition on that will correctly reset your sum at the next non null:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (run_key INT, time_empty INT, Col1 INT, Col2 INT)
INSERT @T (run_key, time_empty) 
VALUES
    (1, 637), (2, NULL), (3, NULL), (4, NULL), 
    (5, 2967), (6, 1000), (7, NULL), (8, NULL);

SELECT  run_key,
        time_empty,
        time_empty_rt = CASE WHEN time_empty IS NULL THEN NULL
                            ELSE SUM(time_empty) 
                                    OVER (PARTITION BY Col1, Col2, IslandID
                                            ORDER BY run_key 
                                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND CURRENT ROW)
                        END
FROM    (   SELECT  run_key,
                    time_empty, 
                    Col1,
                    Col2,
                    IslandID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Run_key)
                                 - ROW_NUMBER() 
                                            OVER(PARTITION BY 
                                                    Col1, 
                                                    Col2, 
                                                    CASE WHEN time_empty IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                                                ORDER BY Run_key)
            FROM    @T
        ) AS t;
```

Comment: This should work. It does rely on `run_key` increasing strictly in steps of 1.

Comment: You are right, not sure why I did that.... I have replaced `run_key - ROW_NUMBER()...`  with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Run_key) - ROW_NUMBER()...` i.e. the correct way to do gaps and islands, and this has removed the requirement for it to increase in steps of 1. Thanks for the heads up.